# I need help understanding kubernetes architecture best practices

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, architecture

I have 2 nodes on GCP in a kubernetes cluster. I also have a load balancer in GCP as well.  this is a regular cluster (not GCK). I am trying to expose my front-end-service to the world. I am trying nginx-ingress type:nodePort as a solution. Where should my loadbalancer be pointing to? is this a good architecture approach?

world --> GCP-LB --> nginx-ingress-resource(GCP k8s cluster) --> services(pods)

to access my site I would have to point LB to worker-node-IP where nginx pod is running. Is this bad practice. I am new in this subject and trying to understand.
Thank you

deployservice:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mycha-service
  labels:
    run: mycha-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mycha-app
```

nginxservice:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort 
  ports: 
  - nodePort: 31000
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress
      labels:
        run: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - nodePort: 31000
        port: 80
        targetPort: 3000
        protocol: TCP
      selector:
        app: nginx-ingress
```

nginx-resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: mycha-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: mycha-service
            servicePort: 80
```

This configuration is not working.

Comment: what is not working? what error you have got?

Answer (score 0):

When you use ingress in-front of your workload pods the service type for workload pods will always be of type clusterIP because you are not exposing pods directly outside the cluster. 
But you need  to expose the ingress controller outside the cluster either using NodePort type service or using Load Balancer type service and for production its recommended to use Loadbalancer type service.

This is the recommended pattern.

```
Client -> LoadBalancer -> Ingress Controller -> Kubernetes Pods
```

Ingress controller avoids usage of kube-proxy and load balancing provided by kube-proxy. You can configure layer 7 load balancing in the ingress itself.

Comment: that doesnt make sense? youre creating an additional hope for no reason? i may be wrong but should the service not be clusterIP and the ingress be the direct ingester of client traffic?

Comment: the kubernetes service type will be clusterip for the pods...for ingress controller you need to create a service for it to be accessible outside the cluster...that service can either be nodeport or load balancer

Comment: how can I set up  my own LoadBalancer. I have the ip for my own LB. how can I hook up my ingress with my LB?. When I do type:LoadBalancer for nginx-ingress. the external ip is pending, but i think it shouldn't be pending but somehow i need to pass my LB IP to the ingress.

Comment: Are you using GKE or the kubernetes is managed by you?the existing load balancer that you have is TCP/UDP or  HTTP?

Comment: Have you  tried configuring the TCP/UDP load balancer to point to the worker VM where nginx ingress controller is running ?

Answer (score 0):

The best practise of exposing application is:

```
World > LoadBalancer/NodePort (for connecting to the cluster) > Ingress (Mostly to redirect traffic) > Service
```

If you are using Google Cloud Platform, I would use [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) as it is optimized for containers and configure many things automatically for you.

Regarding your issue, I also couldn't obtain IP address for LB `<Pending>` state, however you can expose your application using `NodePort` and VMs IP. I will try few other config to obtain `ExternalIP` and will edit answer.

Below is one of examples how to expose your app using `Kubeadm` on `GCE`.

On GCE, your VM already have `ExternalIP`. This way you can just use `Service` with `NodePort` and `Ingress` to redirect traffic to proper `services`.

Deploy `Nginx Ingress` using Helm 3 as tiller is not required anymore (`$ helm install nginx stable/nginx-ingress`).

As Default it will deploy service with `LoadBalancer` type but it won't get externalIP and it will stuck in `<Pending>` state. You have to change it to `NodePort` and apply changes.

```
$ kubectl edit svc nginx-nginx-ingress-controller
```

Default it will open `Vi` editor. If you want other you need to specify it

```
$ KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit svc nginx-nginx-ingress-controller
```

Now you can deploy service, deployment and ingress.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fs
spec:
  selector:
    key: app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind:  Deployment
metadata:
  name: mycha-deploy
  labels:
    app: mycha-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mycha-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mycha-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mycha-container
          image: nginx
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mycha-service
  labels:
    app: mycha-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mycha-app
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.pod.svc
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /mycha
        backend:
          serviceName: mycha-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: fs
          servicePort: 80

service/fs created
deployment.apps/fd created
deployment.apps/mycha-deploy created
service/mycha-service created
ingress.extensions/two-svc-ingress created

$ kubectl get svc nginx-nginx-ingress-controller
NAME                             TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-nginx-ingress-controller   NodePort   10.105.247.148   <none>        80:31143/TCP,443:32224/TCP   97m
```

Now you should use your VM ExternalIP (slave VM) with `port` from `NodePort` service. My VM ExternalIP: `35.228.133.12`, service: `80:31143/TCP,443:32224/TCP`

**IMPORTANT**

If you would curl your VM with port you would get response:

```
$ curl 35.228.235.99:31143
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.228.235.99 port 31143: Connection timed out
```

As you are doing this manually, you also **need add `Firewall rule` to allow traffic from outside on this specific port or range**.

Information about creation of `Firewall Rules` can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls).

If you will set proper values (open ports, set IP range (0.0.0.0/0), etc) you will be able to get service from you machine.

Curl from my local machine:

```
$ curl -H "HOST: my.pod.svc" http://35.228.235.99:31143/mycha
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

$ curl -H "HOST: my.pod.svc" http://35.228.235.99:31143/hello
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: fd-c6d79cdf8-dq2d6
```